# Counting repeated patterns from a text file in python?

Tags: python

I need to count a special pattern from a text file.
My code is:

```
sequence = input ("Enter a sequence valid: ")
with open(original_file, 'r') as read_obj:
    for line in read_obj:
        count = 0
        for i in range(len(line)):
            if sequence.upper() == (line[i:i + len(sequence)].upper()):
                count += 1
        print(f"({count}) {line.upper()}", end=' ')
```

the outpu is:

```
Enter a sequence valid : ACA
(0) CATGTCGTAGCTAGCTACTGTACTATTATTATCTGGATCGTAC
 (0) CTATGCGATGCTGACGTATCTAGCTACGTATCGTAGCTGATCTATCGATCGTATCGA
 (0) CATGCTAGTCTAGCTAGCTAGCTAGCGTAGCTACTGAGTCGATC
 (3) ACACACCCCACATTCTCGTACGATTTTCGGCGCGGGGCGGCCTATTATCTGCAT
 (2) ACACAC
 (0) TGTGTG
 (15) ACACACACACACACACACACACACACACACAC
 (1) TAGACAGTCGATCGACTGCAGCTTCG
 (0) CCACCATGGGTGG
 (0) AAAAATTTT
 (0) GGGG
 (0) AAAA
```

I need to count the total of finding pattern for each line for example in this case is **21** for **ACA**.
My text file is:

```
CATGTCGTAGCTAGCTACTGTACTATTATTATCTGGATCGTAC
CTATGCGATGCTGACGTATCTAGCTACGTATCGTAGCTGATCTATCGATCGTATCGA
CATGCTAGTCTAGCTAGCTAGCTAGCGTAGCTACTGAGTCGATC
ACACACCCCACATTCTCGTACGATTTTCGGCGCGGGGCGGCCTATTATCTGCAT
ACACAC
TGTGTG
ACACACACACACACACACACACACACACACAC
TAGACAGTCGATCGACTGCAGCTTCG
CCACCATGGGTGG
AAAAATTTT
GGGG
AAAA
```

Comment: so whats you problem? I cannot find 15 "ACA" in that line, except you also count sub occurencies...so my total count is 13

Comment: use `count`. s = 'ACACACCCCACATTCTCGTACGATTTTCGGCGCGGGGCGGCCTATTATCTGCAT'
print(s.count('ACA'))

Comment: No, That should be 21.

Comment: if a sequence is overlapping like `'ACACA'` would that be a count of 1 or 2?

Comment: that should be 2.

Comment: I found for each line but I need to have the total of pattern too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to count all occurrences including the overlapping ones then you do something like this

```
s = """CATGTCGTAGCTAGCTACTGTACTATTATTATCTGGATCGTAC
CTATGCGATGCTGACGTATCTAGCTACGTATCGTAGCTGATCTATCGATCGTATCGA
CATGCTAGTCTAGCTAGCTAGCTAGCGTAGCTACTGAGTCGATC
ACACACCCCACATTCTCGTACGATTTTCGGCGCGGGGCGGCCTATTATCTGCAT
ACACAC
TGTGTG
ACACACACACACACACACACACACACACACAC
TAGACAGTCGATCGACTGCAGCTTCG
CCACCATGGGTGG
AAAAATTTT
GGGG
AAAA"""

def get_occurrences(s):
    counter = 0
    for i in range(len(s) - 3):
        if s[i:i+3] == "ACA": 
            counter += 1
    return counter

sum([get_occurrences(line) for line in s.split("\n")])
```

This will give you the desired `21`.